# How to combine elements with similar keys?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a RDD with key/value pairs and want to combine elements that have approx same key.

> (144,value)(143,value)(145,value)(...,value)(244,value)(243,value)(245,value)(...,value)(344,value)(342,value)(343,value)(...,value).

I want to combine elements with 144,143,145 key and same with 244,243,245 and 344,342,343.

How can I do this?

Comment: In your case, do you have a formal definition for 'similar' ?

Answer (score 2):

You can always generate a composed key from existing keys. For instance, you can create your own key generator and use it to "group" together same values by this new key.

```
def genKey(value : Int) = {
    if (value == 143 || value == 144 || value == 145) {
        140
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then do something like

```
rdd.map( (key, value) => genKey(key) -> value).reduceByKey(...)
```

to transform the keys in your PairRDD into the new one.

Don't take this method as is. It transforms all the keys into another key, which is the same for several values. You can, of course, return an object of your choice if you prefer; this depends much on your requirements.